# how to do finger print matcher using java

Tags: java, image-processing, fingerprint

I'm currently working on fingerprint matcher project. I finished up to ridge thinning except minutiae marking and matching process. Because I couldn't have a vast knowledge of the algorithm. Can Someone help me?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176)

Comment: sry for that @AndyTurner

Comment: Did you know above question sir? @AndyTurner

Comment: @mahaveer As he stated, its not an actual question. Improve your OP, otherwise I´ll flag it as `unclear what you asking`.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt My Question is how to do mark minutiae in the finger print image and how to match between template image of finger print from database and finger print image.

Comment: Put that in your OP. Btw, SO is not a "how to do xyz?"-site. Also missing is, what you have tried so far and a bit of code would be helpful too.

Comment: are you familiar with www.google.com? The amount of resources you find online on this topic is overwhelming. this is not a research service.